# Would velocity increase?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, momentum, conservation-laws

If you have a body of mass in a vacuum  moving at speed (c) [velocity sorry, not speed, let alone the speed of light or the speed of a wave] with no external forces acting on it.  and it is losing mass (perhaps it's a perfect sphere of ice sublimating at a constant rate and evenly spread over the sphere so as not to create thrust) would the velocity increase because momentum is conserved? 
Because if it does... How? Since there is no external forces acting on it, nor is it creating thrust. 
I stumped my physics teacher with this question maybe someone here will know.

Comment: Why should the velocity increase? The momentum and kinetic energy stays exactly the same the whole time. But of course the body can change it's velocity when it's mass decreases. The work for that acceleration comes from the process within the object - why is it losing mass? It can't simply split itself without some process going on and that requires a force in classical mechanics.

Comment: Consider that whatever mass it loses also still has momentum, and that it is *total* momentum that's conserved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume by "c" you just mean what you said, velocity, not the speed of light (no object with mass could pass by any instrument with that speed).  The momentum that is conserved is the total momentum of all the material, including the gas that is sublimating.  So if the gas sublimates in all directions, it has the same average velocity as the object, so has the same momentum per unit mass.  Hence, conservation of momentum requires that the object not change velocity.  It is wrong to think conservation of momentum implies a change in the object's velocity, that requires forgetting about the momentum of the sublimating gas.  (The easiest way to do any problem like that is to go into the frame of reference of the object, say by imagining being in a rocket moving with it, do the sublimation seen in that frame, and then go back into the original frame.  That should make it very clear why the object's velocity should not change.)

Comment: Yes that c is not even close to being in the right field of physics. I had an A-level physics lesson on waves today and c is wave speed. I'm aware that you'd need an infinite amount of energy to get an object with mass to the speed of light. Thanks for pointing it out I need to sharpen up!

Comment: It's OK, we shouldn't be slaves to standard notation anyway-- you defined your notation, c meant velocity.  But you're right, we almost always mean either the speed of light, or at least wave speed, by the letter c.  Sometimes you'll see a subscript "s" to mean "sound speed" when it's a compression wave.